# Is there an unbounded integrable function with integrable derivative in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, sobolev-spaces

I wonder if there is a differentiable unbounded function $f\in L^1(0,1)$ with $f'\in L^1(0,1)$. The elementary examples $x^\alpha$ or $\log x$ suggest that my question should be answered negatively. However, I have no idea how to prove that such a function can not exist.

Comment: I hope my post is more precise now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work on $(-1,1)$ for simplicity. Then (see Real and Complex Analysis (Rudin), Theorem 7.21):
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(x)\,dx,$$
so it can't get too far from $f(0)$ since $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Seems like I didn't think enough on this issue. Nevertheless,  Thanks for the  answer and the hint on "absolute continuity".